# React-Native : How to snapshot something so that its complete state is maintained

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use a [side menu](https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-side-menu) to drive an app navigation. I was hoping it would work similar to how [TabBarIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html#content) works whereby I could drop content in for each of my nav items and then recall them when a user clicks on the same item again after navigating away.

Currently the content is reloaded each time a user clicks that nav item. Can i save this state properly before moving away. I've tried to copy it but that doesn't help.

e.g.

```
_onNavClick: function(clickedItem){
    if (clickedItem == this.state.currentSideNavID){
        // close menu without changing page
    }else{
        snapShots[this.state.currentSideNavID] =this.state.currentView;

        if (snapShots[clickedItem] != undefined){
            // load saved snapshot
            this.setState({
                currentView:snapShots[clickedItem],
            });
        }else{
            switch (clickedItem){
                case "test_page_1":
                    this.setState({
                        currentView : <BlankPage message={this.state.currentSideNavID} style={styles.page} />
                    });
                break;
                case "test_page_2":
                    this.setState({
                        currentView : <TestPage style={styles.page} />
                    });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

render: function(){
    return (
        <SideMenu menu={menu}>
            {this.state.currentView}
        </SideMenu>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that trying to store a component in state is a pretty bad idea and there be dragons.

Instead, I'd store your entire application state, including whatever information the sub-views require (as well as their children), at a *global* level so it's not tied to these particular views being displayed/maintained in memory.

As an optimization, remove your SideMenu's responsibility to pass those components their state, and instead retrieve it from the global store.

Conveniently, the latter is precisely what libraries like [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux) are meant to solve while emphasizing the former as good practice.

Sorry to "answer" your question with such generalities, but I don't think what you're trying to achieve is possible in the way you have constructed.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'm going to down the redux route for future projects. Thank you.